# Determine continuity and differentiability

Tags: real-analysis, multivariable-calculus, partial-derivative

Could you tell me how to determine continuity and differentiability of functions with two or more variables?

I know how to do it for fairly simple functions, such as $f(x,y)=\sqrt{x^k + y^k}$, $f(x,y)=\sin (x^k + y^k)$ and for polynomials continuity is obvious.

We check if the function and its partial derivatives are continuous.

For functions for which it is evident that they are a composition of continuous functions, it is easy to establish continuity.

I have problems determining continuity of more ambitious functions, say $f(x,y)  = \sqrt{xy}(\sqrt{x^2+y^2})^{-1}$ for $(x,y)$ in the domain of this function and $f(x,y) = 0$  elsewhere.

I've also seen functions of this type $(|x|^ky) \cdot (x^2 + x^4)^{-1} $, and I also don't know how to deal with them.

How to calculate $\lim _{(x,y)\rightarrow (0,0)}f(x,y)$ here?

I would appreciate it if you explained to me how to solve such problems on an example of the functions I've mentioned above.

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When the function is not continuous, you can prove it by going to the origin through two special (may not work for *any* two) curves or sequences so that the function approaches two different values. For example, consider the function
$$
f(x, y) = \frac{xy}{x^2 + y^2}
$$
for $(x, y) \neq (0, 0)$ and $f(0, 0) = 0$. We can go along the curve $y = x$ to get
$$
\lim_{x \to 0} f(x, x) = \lim_{x \to 0} \frac{x \cdot x}{x^2 + x^2} = \frac{1}{2}
$$
whereas going along $y = -x$, we get
$$
\lim_{x \to 0} f(x, -x) = \lim_{x \to 0} \frac{x \cdot (-x)}{x^2 + (-x)^2} = -\frac{1}{2}.
$$
So $f$ is clearly not continuous at $(0, 0)$.

To prove continuity, one way is to bound the function by something else which you can show goes to $0$. For example, consider the function
$$
f(x, y) = \frac{|xy|}{\sqrt{x^2 + y^2}}
$$
for $(x, y) \neq (0, 0)$ and $f(0, 0) = 0$. Then, $0 \leq (|x| - |y|)^2 \implies 2|xy| \leq x^2 + y^2$. Thus for $(x, y) \neq (0, 0)$,
$$
0 \leq \frac{|xy|}{\sqrt{x^2 + y^2}} \leq \frac{x^2 + y^2}{2\sqrt{x^2 + y^2}} = \frac{1}{2}\sqrt{x^2 + y^2} \\
\implies 0 \leq \lim_{(x, y) \to (0, 0)} f(x, y) = \lim_{(x, y) \to (0, 0)} \frac{|xy|}{\sqrt{x^2 + y^2}} \leq \lim_{(x, y) \to (0, 0)} \frac{1}{2}\sqrt{x^2 + y^2} = 0
$$
and hence the limit is $\lim_{(x, y) \to (0, 0)} f(x, y) = 0$ which shows $f$ is continuous.

Comment: about your little proof : $(|x|-|y|)^2$ >= 0 so $x^2+y^2 >= 2 * |xy|$

Comment: @Thomas Thanks, thats much quicker and simpler.

Comment: Thank you a lot. It's all much clearer now :)

Comment: I have one more question. I hope it's not too late. If I have $\sqrt{ \sin (x^2 + y^2)}$ in the denominator and $(x,y) \rightarrow (0,0)$, can I use the fact that for $a$ small enough $\sin (a) \approx  a$ and then approximate my function by a function with $\sqrt{ x^2 + y^2}$ in the denominator?

Comment: @Hagrid I think that's the right idea. But in math you must use inequalities. There is no mathematically precise definition of $\approx$, so you cannot logically conclude anything (at least in math). Back to your question, sometimes you might have to work with the Taylor series but in your case I think you can use $\frac{1}{2}(x^2 + y^2) \leq \sin(x^2 + y^2)$ for small enough $x^2 + y^2$ (in other words $(x, y)$ in some ball around $(0, 0)$) which implies $\frac{1}{\sqrt{\sin(x^2 + y^2)}} \leq \frac{2}{\sqrt{x^2 + y^2}}$.